# Shells Vs Disks Method: $\ln(x)$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

y=$\ln(x)$, and the x-axis, and $x=e$ Rotation across the x-axis:

$$V_{shells}=\int_\limits{1}^{e}(\ln(x))^2dx= \pi(e-2)$$

Why is it that when I do the method by shells I have to substract $e-e^x$

$$V_{shells}=\pi(e-2)=2\pi\int_\limits{0}^{1}y(e-e^y)dy$$

Comment: The volume you want to find is the volume obtained by rotating the figure bounded by the curves $f(x)=\ln{x}$, $x=e$ and the x-axis around the y-axis. Is that correct? If you're going to do that using the shell method, your integral should look like this:

$$
V=2\pi\int_{1}^{e}x\ln{x}\,dx.
$$

Comment: @MichaelRybkin It's about the x-axis, but then using shells it should be dy, not dx.

Comment: No, the rotation is about the y-axis. Not about the x-axis. Actually, about which axis do you need to rotate that shape? You didn't state that in the question.

Comment: You get that answer with a rotation about the x-axis. The integral is that of $ln(x)^2$ though, not $xln(x)$ and you can do the integral with a substitution followed by integration by parts.

Comment: @Paul, who are you talking to? Yes, if you're rotating that shape about the x-axis, you get this using the disk method: $$V=\pi\int_{1}^{e}\left(\ln{x}\right)^2\,dx.$$ What I have in my first comment is a rotation about the y-axis using the shell method.

Comment: @MichaelRybkin Better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f(y)=e-e^y$ is the function that represents the distance between the curves $x=e$ and $x=e^y$ on the interval $[0,1]$. When you're integrating, you're basically multiplying $y$ that's constantly changing by that distance which is also constantly changing as you go from $y=0$ to $y=1$. Let me quote [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shell_integration) on this:

> If the function is of the y coordinate and the axis of rotation is the x-axis then the formula becomes:
>
> $$2\pi\int_{a}^{b}yf(y)\,dy$$

In your case, the function $f(y)$ happens to be the distance between the curves $x=e$ and $x=e^y$ because that's what forms the region bounded by $y=\ln{x}$, $x=e$ and the x-axis. That's pretty much all that can be said about this.